# For Ajax, may I use how to use it directly call one py script on the local file server

Tags: python, json

I am new to JS- Ajax, and my code is just like:
$.ajax(
{
    url: "http://192.168.0.1:8080"
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET"
       .......
}

Actually, the url is just running one python script at the backend via python FLASK framework.

So my questions are:
1) if the url is cross-domain (such as from http to https), is the only way using JSONP?
2) May I directly call one python in url, just like: url: "//myfileserver/test/python.py"

Thanks a lot.

Comment: 1) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS